# Bluetooth keyboard must be re-started at every boot

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I just downloaded and installed 14.04 to replace a xubuntu 14.10 that has been crashing on every reboot. Now, with nothing else installed, My Logitech bluetooth keyboard must be turned off and back on after a reboot before it will function, yet the mouse (using the same receiver) works fine.

```
mobo: M4A89GTD-PRO 
Bios: 2101 
cpu: AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 645 Processor 
ram: 6111188 kB 
hdd: ATA OCZ-VERTEX3 
gpu: GeForce GT 440 Mouse / keyboard: M510, K350 single unifying receiver 
Linux 3.13.0-43-generic (x86_64) Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
```

**Update:** I traded several emails with Logitech tech support; he explained that if the keyboard works fine at the BIOS (which it does) and it works fine with Windows 7 (which it does) and it is not possible to reproduce the issue at either the BIOS or on Windows 7 (which it is not) then it is not a keyboard issue, it must be a Ubuntu issue.  He was also quick to point out that Logitech does not provide any support or software for Linux of any flavor.  Not sure if this helps narrow down the problem.

**Update 2:** Based on a suggestion below, I added kbd-reset to the boot options.  It did not help.

**Update 3:** Spent a few hours several times over the holiday weekend, traded another email with Logitech.  Logitech has come out and said that their hardware does not support Ubuntu. Period.  I have plugged in a USB mouse and USB keyboard; they seem to work fine (as long as I don't get a 'read-only' keyboard from Ubuntu  lol!)

**Update 4:**  Not sure if I should mark this as 'solved' or not.  The USB mouse and keyboard are working fine, Logitech says that their bluetooth hardware is not compatible with Linux - only Windows and OSX, and none of the attempts here have corrected the issues with them.  I hate to think that the solution is "use the cheapest POS USB hardware you can find," but all indications point to that as the only solution.  And honestly, I have to agree with Logitech on this one... if the bluetooth hardware works with the BIOS, then quits working with Ubuntu, then the issue must be Ubuntu.

**Last Update**  This issue is still unresolved, and after a month of messing with it I am giving up and wiping 14.04 from my system.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `tail -f /var/log/{kern.log,dmesg,syslog}` when you turn off/on the keyboard?

Comment: The only change between 'on' 'off' and 'on' again was a message in syslog telling me that the job 'cron.daily' was terminated, but I think it was simply a coincidence that that message came up.  But, the keyboard began working immediately.

Comment: Weird... The cannon-method then: Can you add boot option `kbd-reset`?

Comment: Sorry, no joy.  Same behavior.

Comment: next one: `atkbd.reset` (walking in the dark as there were no messages) Sorry about this... Oh, and remove the previous one...

Comment: sorry - I'm also trying to fix graphic driver issues at the same time; I'm starting to get frustrated with the whole pile of poo that 14.04 has turned out to be.  no messages - where do I find messages from boot options?  and - atkbd.reset also did not change anything.

Comment: Yeah, you're doing both with me!  :D  ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19851/discussion-between-fabby-and-snurfle).